# how to trim the white spaces in the output of json webservice asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

Hi (I'm new to JSON this is my 1st webservice)

I have created an Webservice in asp.net that returns JSON data.Every thing works fine but what i need is when fetching the data from the database it should trim the white spaces before it displays.

Because in my data base i have given the field type as nvarchar(100) but inserted the text with <20 characters so in the output i'm getting the result with whitespaces also 
For eg:

```
{"Cargo":[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"devi                ","LastName":"priya               ","Contactno":"965577796 "}]}
```

after the name devi and priya there is lots if spaces.
But the actual result i supposed to get is;

```
{"Cargo":[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"devi","LastName":"priya ","Contactno":"965577796 "}]}
```

Here is my code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;



namespace Webservice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
            //InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        //public string GetEmployees(string SearchTerm) 

        public void GetEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
                foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
               //return serializer.Serialize(rows);
                //return "{ \"Cargo\": " + serializer.Serialize(rows) + "}";
                //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //string strJSON = js.Serialize(new { Cargo = rows });
                this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                this.Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { Cargo = rows }));
                //return serializer.Serialize(new { Cargo = rows });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //return errmsg(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

can any one please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: hi the following code helps me to trim the white spaces:row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col].ToString().Trim());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi the following code helps me to trim the white spaces:

```
row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col].ToString().Trim());
```